# A question on Fourier coefficients

Tags: differential-geometry, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am working on a question on closed curves but get stuck on a technical question. Suppose $x(t)=\left(x_1(t), x_2(t), x_3(t)\right):[0,2 \pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is a smooth closed curve satisfying $x_i(t)=$ $\sum_{n=1}^2\left(c_{i, n} \cos (n t)+s_{i, n} \sin (n t)\right)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i(t)^2\equiv 1$ (i.e. $x(t)$ lies on the unit sphere).
Does it follow that there exists $n \in\{1,2\}$ such that $c_{i, n}=s_{i, n}=0$ for all $i$? (If $x(t)$ is a plane curve instead it is true.)

One idea is that by considering the Fourier expansion of $1=\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i(t)^2$, we can obtain 9 equations, since the higher Fourier modes of a constant function vanish. So, we have a system of 9 quadratic equations in 6 unknowns. But the system is quite complicated, and I have no clue how to solve it.

Comment: I don’t see how it’s true even in the plane, unless you assume it is a regular curve with constant speed. In space, it certainly won’t be true — the projection into the plane can be very complicated. Are you sure Fourier is the right approach?

Comment: @TedShifrin The assumption $x_i(t)=\sum_{n=1}^2\left(c_{i, n} \cos (n t)+s_{i, n} \sin (n t)\right)$ imposes a strict restriction on the possible form of the curve. Of course it's not true that a general space curve on the sphere has only one Fourier mode.

Comment: For plane curve, my approach is the following. We claim that if $z(t)=\sum_{0<|n| \leq 2} d_n e^{\text {int }}$ satisfies $|z(t)|=$ constant for $d_n \in \mathbb{C}$, then there exists $0<|n| \leq 2$ such that $z(t)=d_n e^{i n t}$.

Comment: Let $\omega=e^{i t}$, then $|z(t)|^2=\left|\sum_{0<|n| \leq 2} d_n \omega^n\right|^2=\sum_{n=-4}^4 c_n \omega^n$ where $c_n=\sum_{p+q=n} d_p \overline{d_{-q}}$. Note that the Fourier series of $|z(t)|^2$ can only contain the constant term. Since $c_n=0$ if $n \neq 0$, by inspecting $c_2$ and $c_4$, we conclude
1. either $d_1$ or $d_{-1}$ vanishes, and
2. either $d_2$ or $d_{-2}$ vanishes.

Comment: So $z(t)$ can contain at most two terms, i.e. $z(t)=d_p \omega^p+d_q \omega^q$ where $|p|=1$ and $|q|=2$. But then the non-zeroth order Fourier coefficient $c_{p-q}=d_p \bar d_q$ must be zero, and hence $z(t)$ consists of only one term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tedious calculation (done partly by Mathematica), I was able to prove it myself.

By a long but straightforward computation, we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i(t)^2=& \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{n=1}^2\left(c_{i n}^2+s_{i n}^2\right) \\
&+\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 c_{i 1} c_{i 2}+\sum_{i=1}^3 s_{i 1} s_{i 2}\right) \cos (t)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 c_{i 1}^2-\sum_{i=1}^3 s_{i 1}^2\right) \cos (2 t) \\
&+\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 c_{i 1} c_{i 2}-\sum_{i=1}^3 s_{i 1} s_{i 2}\right) \cos (3 t)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 c_{i 2}^2-\sum_{i=1}^3 s_{i 2}^2\right) \cos (4 t) \\
&+\left(\sum_{i=1}^3\left(-c_{i 2} s_{i 1}+c_{i 1} s_{i 2}\right)\right) \sin (t)+\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 c_{i 1} s_{i 1}\right) \sin (2 t) \\
&+\left(\sum_{i=1}^3\left(c_{i 2} s_{i 1}+c_{i 1} s_{i 2}\right)\right) \sin (3 t)+\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 c_{i_2} s_{i_2}\right) \sin (4 t).
\end{align*}

As the LHS of the above is 1, by uniqueness of Fourier series, all the Fourier coefficients except the first one are zero.
Let $C_n=\left(c_{1 n}, c_{2 n}, c_{3 n}\right), S_n=\left(s_{1 n}, s_{2 n}, s_{3 n}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ for $n=1,2$. Then from the above, we get
\begin{align*}
&C_1 \cdot C_2=0, \; S_1 \cdot S_2=0, \;
C_2 \cdot S_1=0, \; C_1 \cdot S_2=0, \;
C_1 \cdot S_1=0, \; C_2 \cdot S_2=0, \\
&|C_1|^2=|S_1|^2, \; |C_2|^2=|S_2|^2.
\end{align*}
We claim that either $C_1=S_1=0$ or $C_2=S_2=0$. If not, then from the last two equations above, all $C_1, S_1, C_2, S_2$ are non-zero. But then from the orthogonal relations in the first 6 equations above, we have that $\left\{C_1, C_2, S_1, S_2\right\}$ forms an orthogonal basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$, a contradiction.